# Error 404 en proyecto Codeigniter publicado en Azure Cloud Web App

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, web, azure

Pues soy nueva poniendo en marcha este tipo de proyectos y pues de momento estoy tratando de configurar un proyecto de codeigniter dentro del portal cloud de azure, por medio de un web app. La cuestión es que me tira un error 404 cuando intenta accesar al metodo de validacion de credenciales en el login, y pues supongo que sera igual para los otros metodos de los controladores. Tal parece como si solo tomara en cuenta el default_controller.

Las carpetas las tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
xpbc2017
   application
   config
                routes.php
                database.php
                config.php
    views
    controllers
               login
                      backend
                              ValidateUser.php
               usuario
               Login.php
      models
      system
      templates
      web.config
      index.php
```

Este es mi web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
       <rewrite>
         <rules>
           <rule name="Rule" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
             <conditions>
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
               <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|eot|woff|ttf|svg|txt|pdf|swf)$"  matchType="IsFile"  negate="true" />
             </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
           </rule>
         </rules>
       </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Este es mi config

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config['base_url'] = 'https://xpbc-app-2018.azurewebsites.net/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language']     = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';
$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$config['error_views_path'] = '';
$config['cache_path'] = '';
$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;
$config['encryption_key'] = 'pass';
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_prefix']        = '';
$config['cookie_domain']        = '';
$config['cookie_path']          = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']        = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']      = FALSE;
.
.
```

y este mi routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
$route['login'] = 'login/frontend/Login';
$route['validateUser'] = 'login/backend/ValidateUser/newUser';
$route['menu_principal'] = 'MainMenu';
$route['usuario-agregarUsuario'] = 'usuario/AgregarUsuario';
$route['usuario-modificarUsuario'] = 'usuario/ModificarUsuario';
$route['usuario-eliminarUsuario'] = 'usuario/EliminarUsuario';
$route['usuario-consultarUsuario'] = 'usuario/ConsultarUsuario';
```

Este tema realmente me ha dado dolores de cabeza y pues por eso estoy aca pidiendo de su ayuda, algun consejo o una pista de lo que pueda ser estare poniendola en marcha, y les agradezco de antemano a quienes se tomen la molestia de comentar.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tu sitio web al rellenar el formulario y enviarlo redirecciona a:

`https://xpbc-app-2018.azurewebsites.net/login/validateUser`

Veo que no estás eliminando el `index.php` de `index_page` por lo tanto la url debería de ser:

`https://xpbc-app-2018.azurewebsites.net/index.php/login/validateUser`

En todo caso si a tu sitio web le quieres quitar el `index.php` puedes hacerlo por medio de un archivo `.htaccess` en la raíz del sitio el cual debe de contener lo siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Por consiguiente tu `$config['index_page']` debe de quedar vacío:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Por lo tanto cuando mandes el post de tu formulario lo enviaras por medio de tu `base_url()` y tu controlador:

```
action="<?echo base_url('login/validateUser')?>"
```

Cabe mencionar que recientemente tuve el mismo problema y todo fue ocasionado por que el `base_url()` no estaba bien definido, en local trabajaba bien, pero al subirlo arrojaba esos errores.

Comment: Hola Eduardo! Agradezco mucho el tiempo que te tomaste en responder, pues según entendí, Azure me pide un archivo web.config , en lugar del .htaccess, he descubierto que el archivo routes.php no lo esta reconociendo, ya que en mi form llamo a la ruta : $route['login/validateUser'] = 'login/backend/ValidateUser/newUser';  la cual me tendria que dirigir a mi metodo login/backend/ValidateUser/newUser verdad? Bueno no lo reconoce y lo que hace es buscar el controlador login y el metodo validateUser. Si tiene una idea de lo que puede ser me ayudarias muchisimo y gracias otra vez.